# Is it possible to use c++ library code that is not in the header?

Tags: c++

I was wondering (for code security reasons) - can user of c++ library use library's classes, function calls, variables that he does not know because he has only a single header with the library?

If he would guess names for classes and calls by looking for text in library file, could he compose a header file that would allow him to use the code?

Comment: Of course. Why not?

Comment: Short answer is yes. Libraries never designed to be secured if you need that you should use something that is outside of C++ scope.

Comment: What do you mean by "code security"?

Comment: thank you for answers, so additional question - is it possible to protect library against such actions? Obfuscating it maybe?

Comment: @MiroJanosik It's not worth it.  The time and effort you spent making in "unhackable" would be better spent making it better since you can't make it "unhackable"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, a header file is really just for convenience. There's nothing stopping a user from recreating the header file using the library's documentation (or even just by reverse engineering the library), and so there's also nothing stopping them from adding parts of the library's public interface that were missed out of the header.

But the header *should* contain the whole public interface, otherwise what's the point of it? Furthermore, libraries should usually be designed such that anything *else* has internal linkage and is not exported. Though not impossible, it is more difficult to use these because the runtime (or static) linker will not resolve your hand-crafted declarations as referring to the symbols in the private part of the library. In normal use, they're considered to be hidden.

This is certainly not a "security" measure as ultimately anything can be hacked away, but a library's internals are generally considered to be safely tucked away in terms of easy access.

If you wanted to prevent a bad actor from gaining *any* access to your library's internals, you would have to do several things:

1. Decide how bad an actor you want to resist
2. Decide what form of attack you want to resist
3. Decide how strong an attack you want to resist
4. Decide how much usability you want to sacrifice in the attempt
5. Realise that it's entirely futile and stop trying

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, at least for accessing global variables that have external linkage.  Imagine:

foo.cpp

```
int foo = 42;
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
extern int foo;

int main() {

    std::cout << foo;
}
```

There is no header file connecting `main.cpp` to `foo.cpp` but since we know the name `foo` we can use `extern` in `main.cpp` to tell the compiler it is defined somewhere else and the linker will give us access to it.

Comment: _If_ it has external linkage yes. I wonder whether the OP is thinking more of non-exported internals (because everything else should be "in the header")

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've amended my disclaimer. I'm not sure if they want non-exported symbols or not.

Comment: Cool, well we'll see